# How to position Confirm Dialog over Dialog window?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I'm trying to position **Confirm Dialog** right over **Dialog window** but can't get it to work. In order to position my Dialog window based on user's click, I'm using **positionTop** and **positionLeft**, but these don't seem to work when working with Confirm Dialog. My question is how to show/move **Confirm Dialog** in the middle of **Dialog window** and **NOT** in the middle of the page?

NOTE:

- I'm using PrimeNG for my Dialogs.
- Just click on any row to see my Dialog window and then click on Open to see Confirm Dialog.

**Here's my code:**

[**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/GJkLGrZEsZX1P15fq5ij?p=preview)

```
<p-confirmDialog header="Confirmation" icon="fa fa-question-circle" width="330"></p-confirmDialog>
<p-dialog appendTo = "body" header="Title" [(visible)]="display" modal="modal" width="350" height="300" positionLeft="{{positionLeft}}" positionTop="
{{positionTop}}">
{{personData}}
<button type="text" (click)="confirm()" pButton icon="fa-check" label="OPEN"></button>
</p-dialog>
```

Comment: Hmm... I don't think it's possible. At least, it's not planned like that. Using another `p-dialog` could be a solution maybe ?

Comment: It might be possible if you know the coordinates of the cursor after you have clicked on 'Open' button. But it wouldn't be beautiful so if I were you, I would use another `p-dialog`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `positionLeftConfirmation` and `positionTopConfirmation` the top left confirmation dialog coordinates. If you want this confirmation dialog to be centered inside the parent one, its left coordinate will be :

> positionLeftConfirmation = positionLeft (of the parent dialog) + parentDialogWidth/2 - dialogWidth/2.

In your case, parentDialogWidth=350 and dialogWidth=330 so

```
this.positionLeftConfirmation = this.positionLeft + (350-330)/2;
```

Similarly,

```
this.positionTopConfirmation = this.positionTop + (300-200)/2;
```

See working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6VplQUM0505wwvzhnClY?p=preview)

Comment: Just toggle `visible` property with `this.displayConfirmation = false;` (I edited my Plunker)

Comment: Glad to help you !